# Google API redirect change no apply

Tags: java, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-api-java-client

I have been developing an app which uses Google Drive API so I had use OAuth id client redirect to `http://localhost:8080/Callback` but now I have published it so I changed it to `http://myURL/Callback`.

However, changes seems to don't apply since it is asking to open the following URL:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=offline&client_id=my_client_id&redirect_uri=http://localhost:46517/Callback&response_type=code&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
```

and if I try to open it I obviosly get `Error: redirect_uri_mismatch` since I deleted localhost as authorized redirect.

Here is the code I use to connect with Google API

```
public FileSP downloadFile(String fileId, String clientSecretPath){

    FileSP fileSP = null;
    String extension = null;
    try {

        Drive driveService = _getDriveService(clientSecretPath);
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        File file = driveService.files().get(fileId).execute();
       //do stuff

    } catch (IOException e) {
        String mess = "downloadFile(): " 
                + (e.getMessage()!=null?". "+e.getMessage():"")
                + (e.getCause()!=null?". "+e.getCause():"");
        logger.error(mess);
    }
    return fileSP;
}


private Drive _getDriveService(String clientSecretPath) throws IOException {
    Credential credential = _authorize(clientSecretPath);
    return new Drive.Builder(
            HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
            .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
            .build();
}


private Credential _authorize(String clientSecretPath) throws IOException {

    GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets =
        GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(clientSecretPath)));

    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
            new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                    HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
            .setDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_FACTORY)
            .setAccessType("offline")
            .build();
    Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(
        flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
    System.out.println(
            "Credentials saved to " + DATA_STORE_DIR.getAbsolutePath());
    return credential;
}
```

Comment: The redirect error page should be showing you the Redirect URI that its coming from and the one that you are sending.   Remember it needs to match exactly.   BTW you can have more then one so you could have left localhost.

Comment: It says it is going to http://localhost:39361/Callback the problem is that I want it to be myurl.com/Callback, not localhost but it still keeps asking for it (that's also why I deleted localhost as redirect, just to be sure)

Comment: Are you running this compiled or are you running it debug?   To run it from your website your going to have to host it up there and run it there.   The library auto sends the redirect uri from where its coming from.   if its saying localhost it implies to me that you are running this debug.

Comment: No, I'm running it compiled. I think it might be `new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");`  since LocalServerReceiver says `Constructor that starts the server on "localhost" selects an unused port`but I don't know what should I use instead of it

Comment: @DaImTo maybe using `new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setHost("mydomain.com").build()` could help?

Comment: maybe   I have no experience with web hosted java apps.  Mostly with C# the libraries are close though.  check this https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/oauth2#web_server_applications   No matter what your going to have to get it to stop adding the random port the port needs to be static as the redirect uri has to exactly match what you are sending it from.

Comment: you need to edit the clients secret file to match the value you configured on the developer console. Notethat you can have multiple redirect URLs configured, so eg. you can have localhost *and* myurl.com to make testing easier.